# SQL Server Select where stage/sequence has been missed or is out of sequence

Tags: sql-server, select, sequence, stage

I have a table that has `families_id`, `date`, `metric_id`

A record gets inserted for each `families_id` there will be a `date` & `metric_id` 1-10.

So there should be 10 records for each `families_id`, the records get inserted with a date an each should follow on from each other. So `metric_id` 10 date should be greater than `metric_id` 6 date.

On mass how can I select where they have

1. Missed a `metric_id`
2. The date for the `metric_id` 6 is before the date for `metric_id` 2

Comment: Can you show some sample data and also what you have tried so far?

Comment: Here is some sample data 

FID MID  Date
0 1 2014-02-21
1 1 2003-09-19
1 9 2015-02-05
1 10 2004-02-05
2 1 2002-07-19
2 10 2002-11-25
3 1 2002-11-19
3 2 2003-02-13
4 7 2003-04-24
4 8 2005-10-13
4 9 2004-10-12

I have tried a CTE which nearly works for the dates being before each other when the metric_id is the one above it

Comment: Can you put the sample data in your question? The comments do not format it so it is usable at all.

Comment: Also show your CTE query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use row_number to assign an ordinal to the metric_id and date for each family, then they should match - also metric_id, 1,2,3,4... should match with its calculated row_number(), also 1,2,3,4....

```
SELECT IQ.* FROM (SELECT families_id, [date], metric_id, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY families_id ORDER BY [date]) rn_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY families_id ORDER BY metricid) rn_metric FROM YourTable) IQ 
    WHERE IQ.rn_date != IQ.rn_metric;

--should detect wrongly ordered metric_ids
SELECT IQ.* FROM (SELECT families_id, [date], metric_id, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY families_id ORDER BY [date]) rn_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY families_id ORDER BY metricid) rn_metric FROM YourTable) IQ 
    WHERE IQ.metric_id != IQ.rn_metric;
```

Another possibility - detect a metricID where the date is earlier for a higher id

```
    SELECT y1.families_id, y1.metric_id FROM yourtable y1
                    WHERE 
                    EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM yourtable y2 WHERE y1.families_id = y2.families_id 
                                                            AND
                                                            y2.date < y1.date 
                                                            AND
                                                            y2.metricid > y1.metricid)
```